# How to save the image generated by Plot3D as svg?

Tags: export, svg-format, plotting

```
pic11 = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}];Export["ff.svg", pic11]
```

The generated svg diagram is very vague, why is this? How to convert the map generated by Plot3D into svg format?

Comment: 3D objects are `Rasterize`d before being converted into SVG, which is why you get the output that you do. Most 2D plots aren't rasterised, so if you do `pic11 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}]; Export["ff.svg", pic11]` it's a nice scaleable vector image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation page on[`SVG`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/SVG.html):

[image]

Note that the last bullet point says the format is ***intended two-dimensional graphics***.